# OpenCV VideoCapture Crashes on Large Video Size

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to read raw avi video of size 2448x2050. Every time I try to read a frame, the program crashes with a seg fault. The same program works properly for smaller sized videos.

Here is a sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(argv[1]);
    if(!cap.isOpened())
        return -1;
    cv::Mat frames;
    cv::namedWindow("Window", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

    for(;;)
    {
        // error here
        cap >> frames;
        // ........
        cv::imshow("Window", frames);
        cv::waitKey(33);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output for valgrind:

```
==30166== Invalid read of size 1
==30166==    at 0x9ECD550: sws_convertPalette8ToPacked24 (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so.2.1.1)
==30166==    by 0x9ED13AA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so.2.1.1)
==30166==    by 0x9ED385A: sws_scale (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so.2.1.1)
==30166==    by 0x4E5066D: CvCapture_FFMPEG::retrieveFrame(int, unsigned char**, int*, int*, int*, int*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E5071A: cvRetrieveFrame_FFMPEG (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E4FB88: CvCapture_FFMPEG_proxy::retrieveFrame(int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E4E4BA: cv::VideoCapture::retrieve(cv::Mat&, int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E4E2A6: cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::Mat&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E4E209: cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x401330: main (in /home/rumman/temp/Video)
==30166==  Address 0x18897a10 is 5,015,952 bytes inside a block of size 5,018,408 free'd
==30166==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30166==    by 0x8CD0113: av_destruct_packet (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.54.35.0)
==30166==    by 0x8CD04B3: av_free_packet (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.54.35.0)
==30166==    by 0x4E50BB8: CvCapture_FFMPEG::grabFrame() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E50C38: cvGrabFrame_FFMPEG (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E4F934: CvCapture_FFMPEG_proxy::grabFrame() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E4E450: cvGrabFrame (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E4E46C: cv::VideoCapture::grab() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E4E241: cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::Mat&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x4E4E209: cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.8)
==30166==    by 0x401330: main (in /home/rumman/temp/Video)
```

Comment: What is `frames` and how do you declare it?

Comment: I forgot to add that to my question, it's there now.

Comment: after cap >> frames you should always test if (frames.empty ()) continue // or break or print an error or sth. before trying to process an empty image.

Comment: The bug is in the cap >> frames statement itself right now. Checking if frame is empty before processing, but currently it doesn't get to that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was only happening when using Raw video and had nothing to do with the video resolution.

[The patch fix can be found here](http://code.opencv.org/attachments/1735/ffmpeg_raw_video_bug_for_OpenCV_2410.patch).